# Piping buffers in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ibm-watson

I am new to node js and am getting confused by streams. I have audio recording continuously from my computer microphone and am converting it to node js buffers. I am trying to to send those buffers to the IBM Watson server for transcription into text but I keep receiving the error: `error event:  [Error: write after end]`. I have seen other posts about this suggesting its a problem with the asynchronous nature of node js. However, I have not been able to successfully apply those posts.

Here is a code snippet:

```
var bufferStream = function (buffer) {        
    streamifier.createReadStream(buffer).pipe(recognizeStream);
```

where recognizeStream is the stream to the Watson server. This function gets called for every 16 bits of audio. The error repeats the same number of times as the number of buffers that have been piped. For example, after 3 buffers have been piped, the error appears three times. I thought maybe the piped streams were never getting removed.

Can anyone nudge me in the right direction here? Thanks

Comment: I might be able to help here, but I'd need to see more of your code. Can you post the complete JS (excluding any credentials)?

Comment: I have changed my code significantly since this post and at one point was getting responses from the server that appeared to be working. However, there was an error in the data I was sending so it was not able to transcribe it to text. I believe I have fixed this problem and am going to reattempt this, hopefully within a week. I will post my updated code once I get a chance to test it.